# How to exclude more then one path from error prone?

Tags: errorprone

I would like to exclude a few directories form error prone. I was trying to use a XepExcludedPaths flag but it seems that it works only for the one path which is a regular expresion of excluded location.

```
options.errorprone.errorproneArgs.add("-XepExcludedPaths:.*/legacy/model/.*")
```

works

```
options.errorprone.errorproneArgs.add("-XepExcludedPaths:.*/new/model/.*,.*/build/.*")
```

doesn't

Is it possible? I used wrong separator?

Answer (score 2):

It's a single regular expression (literally compiled [using `Pattern.compile`](https://github.com/google/error-prone/blob/745fbe315c7161d69232e12552dd08db4a8eecb6/check_api/src/main/java/com/google/errorprone/ErrorProneOptions.java#L440)), so use a pipe instead of a comma:

```
options.errorprone.errorproneArgs.add("-XepExcludedPaths:(.*/new/model/.*|.*/build/.*)")
```

or

```
options.errorprone.errorproneArgs.add("-XepExcludedPaths:.*/(new/model|build)/.*")
```